# HTTP Error 404.17 - BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.1 WCF Service

Tags: wcf, iis, biztalk, biztalk-2010, esb-toolkit-2.1

I've installed the BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.1 (BTS 2010) onto a Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit laptop. This installs a number of WCF services, including ExceptionService.svc. When I try to browse the service I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found 
>   The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler

```
Module  StaticFileModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070032
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/ESB.Exceptions.Service/ExceptionService.svc
Physical Path   C:\Projects\Microsoft.Practices.ESB\Source\Samples\Management Portal\ESB.Exceptions.Service\ESB.Exceptions.Service\ExceptionService.svc
Logon Method    Negotiate
Logon User  RB-T510\Rob
```

The service is running under the EsbPortalNetworkAppPool which I have tried in both Classic and Integrated Modes.

I've run the same install onto a Win 2008x64 VM and it works. Unfortunately, I need to get it to work on the Win 7 Host also. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread for a similar question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkesb/thread/634865cf-1a6c-4b24-8ab8-6f0fc53a8ad9. They suggested switching the app pool to DefaultAppPool as well as using the ESB config tool to setup the services.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Looking at the script mappings added by the install, i noticed they were all .Net 4 mappings for the .svc type. When I changed the app pool to .Net 4 the 3 .svc sites all worked. Unfortunately the main ESB portal site stopped working at this point as it doesn't want to be .Net 4. So I set up another app pool using the same credentials (network service) but .Net 2 and assigned the main ESB portal site this app pool. Now it all fires up nice a pretty like.